# Unable to create Azure App Service with Docker Compose and Mongodb

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I have Azure Container Registry

```
xxxxxxxx.azurecr.io
```

Inside of it I have 1 image

```
learning-docker01/api
```

Next, I create App Service. I select Docker Container as publish option and following options:

- **Options:** - Docker Compose (Preview)
- **Image Source** - Azure Container Registry
- **Registry** - xxxxxxxx

Next I select my docker-compose.yaml file. The configuration looks like this:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  docker001.api:
    image: xxxxxxxx.azurecr.io/learning-docker01/api
    build:
      context: ./Docker001.API
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=docker
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Then I hit Review & Create and everything deploys smoothly.

**The problem** - after deployment, if I view Log Stream (Preview) I see the following Errors:

```
DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, 
response={"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/mongo/manifests/latest: 
unauthorized: incorrect username or password"}

----

Pulling docker image mongo failed:

---

Container for learningdocker001_mongo_0_986c7f1a site learningdocker001 is unhealthy, Stopping site.
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. Everything runs fine locally. On Azure docker001.api service runs but mongo service doesn't.

Comment: Couple of general remarks: Docker compose on App Services has been in preview for a long time. I cannot give you a definitive answer, but I would not count on this becoming ever GA. Second, why would you want to host your own Mongo DB in a container? You will need to take care of persistence, backup etc. Since you are in the cloud, I would highly recommend to look at a managed service like Cosmos DB

Comment: I agree on persistence. I'm just playing around and trying to learn docker in general. Kind of want to understand why it's not working.

Comment: Did you set up authentication? Described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-app-service-to-deploy-the-image-from-the-registry

Comment: From step 4 onwards seem to have fixed it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-app-service-to-deploy-the-image-from-the-registry . Thank you for help.

Comment: glad to hear it. I created an answer for it

Comment: @silent A small update. I believe the problem is with Azure Container Registry as image source. If you use Docker Compose and reference (for example) rabbitmq:latest image, it tries to download it from mcr.microsoft.com, but it does not exist on mcr.microsoft.com (https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/catalog?search=rabbitmq), so it fails. It's probably the same with MongoDb. At least that is my theory. The workaround is to create and upload your own image to ACR.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up authentication to allow the App Service to pull images from the ACR.

Recommended way is to use the Managed Identity. Detailed setup description here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-app-service-to-deploy-the-image-from-the-registry